# How can I guess server socket type

Tags: socket, unix-sockets

I try to connect to my UNIX-socket server using openbsd-netcat, but have an error:

```
connect(): Protocol wrong type for socket
```

My socket type is `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, and it seems that `nc` tries to open it as `SOCK_DGRAM` or `SOCK_STREAM`. BTW, `nc` can't connect to anonymous UNIX-sockets (which name started with '\0').

So I wonder is there any ways to get socket type information from server to change arguments of `socket()` for successful connection? Or there's only one way: to look over all types while `socket()` will succeed?

Let me explain: what is the right thing to do in a situation where the client doesn't know the type of socket to which he needs to connect?

Comment: *"what is the right thing to do in a situation where the client doesn't know the type of socket to which he needs to connect?"* - try what it might be. socket name, socket type, application protocol ... are needed to contact the peer like the full email address and not just parts of it are needed to send an email.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, let's say I know server IP and socket port, now I want to connect to socket, but don't know its type. Isn't there a way to determine this data without iterating over?

Comment: *"Isn't there a way to determine this data without iterating over?"* - No. The same with port or IP - if you don't know these you need to guess and try.

Comment: I don't know much about BSD (my knowledge is mostly Linux Oriented)... There should usually be some way to list open sockets on a system.  Eg: `sockstat` https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-lists-open-internet-unix-domain-sockets.html I would assume this could let you discover the socket type.